# XSLT for namespace modify in OSB - namespace prefix oddity?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, osb

When running an XSLT transform in Oracle Service Bus 10gR3, the output XML appears differently to how it would appear using a standard XSLT processor.

Input XML:

```
<given xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/6">  
  <child>content here</child> 
</given>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{concat(substring-before(namespace-uri(), '/6'),'/7')}" >
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<ns1537:given xmlns:ns1537="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/7">
  <ns1538:child xmlns:ns1538="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/7">content here</ns1538:child>
</ns1537:given>
```

As you can see, each node is being assigned a different incremental prefix? And also, the namespace attribute is included in each different node? I would have expected the output XML to be as follows:

```
<given xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/7">
  <child>content here</child> 
</given>
```

Can anyone explain why OSB's XSLT processor is producing the output as shown? And what can I do to get the expected output wihtout namespace prefixes, etc?

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Comment: My guess here, but wouldn't the prefixes themselves be independent of the translation?  It's messy, but OSB is a proxy service to hundreds or thousands of other services, so if you were mixing and matching XSLT's across various components in OSB, wouldn't you be concerned a little if there wasn't some namespace prefixing going on to prevent mixups?

Comment: Hi @Nick Klauer, thanks for your input. I just find that the way the OSB's xsl processor creates a different namespace prefix for each node in the message a little strange considering all the nodes fall into the same namespace. It doesn't cause any problems as such, but found it to be a little strange nonetheless. Thanks again, PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What difference will it make if it defines the namespace prefix or not. As long as the elements are qualified by proper namespace. Moreover, namespace prefix makes the life easier for humans to read the xml. Since, there is nothing wrong with the XML created by OSB, no, there is no way you can remove the prefix. You should read this [Namespaces in XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-names11-20060816/#sec-intro).

Comment: Hi @palakmathur, thanks for your input. You are right in that it doesn't make any difference and indeed, doesn't really cause any problems. But still, I find it strange that OSB's processor creates a different prefix for each node in the transformed xml when all the nodes fall under the same namespace. And you are also right in that I wasn't able to remove these prefixes. To that end, I'm accepting your answer as is. Thanks again, PM.